# what does the question mark in tensorflow shape mean?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm looking into magenta code, and printing its tensor object. I got this result:

```
Tensor("fully_connected/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 38), dtype=float32)
```

What does this question mark in shape mean?

Comment: Could you please tell me how to set a placeholder for such kind of tensor? I mean the shape of the placeholder. Thank you.

Comment: @ytutow [use None as a dimension when creating the tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorShape)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It means that first dimension is not fixed in the graph and it can vary between run calls

Comment: Thank you very much. It makes sense because I'm dealing with RNN and sequential data.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please tell me how to set a placeholder for such kind of tensor? I mean the shape.

Comment: @yutow
for example:
img_holder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])

Comment: Can you please in short explain the meaning of "graph" and "calls" regarding your answer?