# Tensorflow what is the difference between None, -1 and ? when specifying tensor shape?

Tags: python, tensorflow, dynamic, reshape, tensor

I have frequently seen the use of the symbols "***None***", "***-1***" and "***?***" to let the program dynamically define a tensor's dimension (such as the batch size), seemingly to the same effect:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 48, 48, 3], name='InputData')

input = tf.reshape(input, [-1, input_size])

foo("bar", shape=(?,48), dtype=float32)
```

Are there any functional differences to using any one of these symbols over the other?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: As far as I know the None keyword is the only one that's accepted by tf.placeholder, and reshape only accepts -1  as the new tensor shape which is confusing because in the tensorflow documentation both of these functions take a shape object as their second argument. I'm not so sure about the use case of the ? symbol, there's a similar post about that at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40951602/what-does-the-question-mark-in-tensorflow-shape-mean but they didn't mention whether None of -1 were acceptable inputs.

Comment: Ok thank you. I'm really sorry but I cannot answer you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think of it this way:

`None` means an unspecified dimension. So if for example you define a placeholder, you use `None` to say "this dimension can have any size".
A placeholder can have multiple `None` dimensions. This simply means multiple dimensions can be different size. Even the whole shape can be `None` to specify an unknown number of dimensions.

`-1` is an instruction to Tensorflow to *infer* the size of the dimension on its own. In `tf.reshape(input, [-1, input_size])`, this means "reshape it such that the second dimension is `input_size`, and the first dimension is whatever is needed to match the total number of elements".
This does *not* necessarily mean that the dimension is unknown, as it is for `None`. If your input tensor has a known size of 10 elements, and you reshape to `[-1, 2]`, Tensorflow is able to infer the full shape `[5, 2]`.
`-1` is purely for convenience. You could always write down the shape explicitly instead of letting Tensorflow infer it. `None` on the other hand is necessary for accepting variable-size tensors.
You can only ever have one `-1` in a shape. Multiple ones don't make sense because it would be impossible to infer the shape. E.g. if you have 12 elements in a tensor, reshaping to `[-1, -1, 2]` is undefined -- should we do `[3, 2, 2]`? `[2, 3, 2]`? `[6, 1, 2]`?...

Finally, the question mark is just what Tensorflow uses to mark an "unknown" dimension when *printing* tensors and/or their shapes. The example you posted would actually produce a syntax error -- you cannot use question marks yourself. Causes of unknown dimensions can of course be placeholders with `None` dimensions, and often tensors that are defined in terms of placeholders (i.e. the result of some ops applied to them) will have unknown dimensions as well. Also some ops may not specify (parts of) their output shape which can also result in unknowns.

There are likely some more technicalities I missed here, but as a rule of thumb: Use `None` for placeholders and use `-1` for reshape. This should cover the majority of use cases.