# What does TensorFlow shape (?,) mean?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm getting the shape of a TensofFlow tensor as:

`(?,)`

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40953146/5353461) says that the `?` means that the dimension is not fixed in the graph and it can vary between run calls.

What does the `?` mean in conjuction with the trailing comma?

Documentation chapter and verse would be appreciated. I find syntax very difficult to google.

Comment: Surely the `(X,)` indicates that the value is inside a container similar to a [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-tuple), with `X` as the only element? Eg, `print(tuple([2]))` will output `(2,)`. `(?,)` should therefore mean that the shape of your tensor is 1d, and its length is  not fixed. Compare to output of numpy shape of 1d array

Comment: @grshankar I already linked to that question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comma means that the dimension is represented as a *1-elem tuple* instead an int.

Each tensor, when created, is by default a n-dim:

```
import tensorflow as tf
t = tf.constant([1, 1, 1])
s = tf.constant([[1, 1, 1],[2,2,2]])

print("0) ", tf.shape(t))
print("1) ", tf.shape(s))

0)  Tensor("Shape_28:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
1)  Tensor("Shape_29:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
```

However, you can reshape it to get a more "whole" shape (i.e. n**X**m / n**X**m**X**r... dim):

```
print("2) ", tf.reshape(t, [3,1]))
print("3) ", tf.reshape(s, [2,3]))

2)  Tensor("Reshape_12:0", shape=(3, 1), dtype=int32)
3)  Tensor("Reshape_13:0", shape=(2, 3), dtype=int32)
```

Comment: So only the last dimension is dropped?

Comment: Can you show an example with the output that I got?

Answer (score 2):

Use `tf.shape(tensor)[0]` to get a scalar tensor with the variable dimension. It is useful if you then need to reshape. `tensor.get_shape().as_list()[0]` generates None for shapes with (?, ... ). This is usually the position for the batch size when training models.

Reference: [TF Issues](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7253)