# What does "?" in shape(?,12) means in keras?

Tags: arrays, numpy, deep-learning, tf.keras

While making a machine learning model in keras, I  checked the shape of an element that gives the output (?,12).

I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51960878/what-does-tensorflow-shape-mean) 
stackoverflow answer but did'nt understand what exactly (?,12) shows?

Comment: Assume that you would pass a matrix of shape (n, 12). Where the columns are fixed to 12, but rows could vary through runs.

Answer (score 0):

it means it's a variable shape. This could be for example the batch size.

Have a look at [What is the meaning of the "None" in model.summary of KERAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47240348/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-none-in-model-summary-of-keras)